# Building segmentation

Tags: sql, left-join

I am trying to build an advanced search functionality for a library application. What I have is `Books` and their `Properties`.

So if Books are:

```
1  LOTR
2  Harry Potter 1
3  Harry Potter 2
```

And properties are

```
id  book_id  key        value
1   1        available  0
2   2        available  10
3   2        author     Tolkien
4   3        author     Rowling
5   2        price      150
6   3        price      163
```

What I need is to find Books that have the following `price = 150 and author = (null or Tolkien)`

From what I am capable of I have been able to do this with 2 joins on `properties` but alas, that won't help(this could go on to 10 joins). is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant, but one option could be to `COUNT` up the number of rows matching your conditions and only return book_ids that match all of them:

```
SELECT book_id FROM (
    SELECT book_id
    FROM Properties
    WHERE
        (key = 'price' AND value = 150) OR
        (key = 'author' AND (value IS NULL OR value = 'Tolkein'))
        -- OR condition 3 etc.
) M
GROUP BY book_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: Well, this seems to be doing what I need for the moment!